# rspec error when running rake

Tags: ruby, rspec, rake

I'm a noob, working through a tutorial which many here may know (testfirst.org).  I'm getting the error below in terminal.app, when I try running 'rake':

```
    fname-lnames-macbook-pro:00_hello macbookowner$ rake
    (in /Users/macbookowner/Desktop/learn_ruby-master)
    /Users/macbookowner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:216: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users in PATH, mode 040777
    /Users/macbookowner/Desktop/learn_ruby-master/00_hello/hello_spec.rb:116:in `require': cannot load such file -- hello (LoadError)
        from /Users/macbookowner/Desktop/learn_ruby-master/00_hello/hello_spec.rb:116:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/macbookowner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rspec-core-2.14.5/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load'
        from /Users/macbookowner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rspec-core-2.14.5/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `block in load_spec_files'
        from /Users/macbookowner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rspec-core-2.14.5/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `each'
        from /Users/macbookowner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rspec-core-2.14.5/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load_spec_files'
        from /Users/macbookowner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rspec-core-2.14.5/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
        from /Users/macbookowner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rspec-core-2.14.5/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
        from /Users/macbookowner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rspec-core-2.14.5/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
    /Users/macbookowner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby -S rspec /Users/macbookowner/Desktop/learn_ruby-master/00_hello/hello_spec.rb -I/Users/macbookowner/Desktop/learn_ruby-master/00_hello -I/Users/macbookowner/Desktop/learn_ruby-master/00_hello/solution -f documentation -r ./rspec_config failed
    fname-lnames-macbook-pro:00_hello macbookowner$
```

**My questions:  What is going wrong?  And how can I fix it?**

*Info:*

1. I got the same/similar error running rvm 1.9.3 and rvm 2.0.0
2. I installed 'gem install rspec' on both rvm versions
3. My best guess is that the hello.rb file [which I created in Sublime Text 2, and saved  on  macbookowner ->Desktop] is not being found by rake.  When I run ls on Desktop, it does show hello.rb.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post the code inside your hello.rb file. It looks like you have a line which shows `require 'hello'`, which ruby is having a hard time finding.

Comment: @Momer:  Ok here is the code from the hello.rb file (it is very basic):        'def hello "Hello!" end'

Comment: Paste in your code from `hello.rb` and `hello_spec.rb` and also list the paths to each file in your question above.

Comment: @Momer.  I actually haven't written anything besides hello.rb.  hello_spec.rb must be something they had written in the 00_hello file?

Comment: @Momer.  The path to hello.rb is /Users/macbookowner/Desktop/hello.rb

Comment: If you look at the error, `/Users/macbookowner/Desktop/learn_ruby-master/00_hello/hello_spec.rb:116:in 'require': cannot load such file -- hello (LoadError)` shows that in `hello_spec.rb`, on line 116, there is a `require 'hello'` which is failing. Likely the file does not exist at the path specified.

Comment: @Momer.  Ok, so does that mean I need to save hello.rb in the same place as 00_hello?

Comment: @Momer.  Got it!  Ok, so for anyone reading this what I didn't know was that I have to save the hello.rb file in 00_hello (where they already have a hello_spec.rb file).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the error,

```
/Users/macbookowner/Desktop/learn_ruby-master/00_hello/hello_spec.rb:116:in 'require': cannot load such file -- hello (LoadError)
```

it shows that in `hello_spec.rb`, on line 116, there is a `require 'hello'` statement which is failing. Likely the file does not exist at the path specified.